# Setting composer layout units to inches in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, units

I open a new composer and select ANSI A for my paper. The notation after the name is "Letter; 8.5inx11in", but the width and height are displayed in mm, and the units selection is grayed out, so I can't change it. The rulers at the top and left of the layout are in mm, and the parameters for "Snap to grid" are also in mm. If I then select "Custom", I can select inches for units, and the Width and Height display as 8.5 and 11. However the rulers in the layout are still in mm, as are the units for the grid.

Can the entire composer project be converted to inches?

qgis 2.01 64 bit
windows 7, 64 bit

Answer (score 6):

You can't (as of 2.12). The "units" selection in the composition properties tab only changes the units for the display page size. Everything else is hardcoded to use mm (ie rulers, item positions, item sizes, etc).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this problem is fixed in QGIS 2.8.1 :
[image]

Are you able to reproduce this?

Comment: I am having the same issue as above, and have not been able to reproduce your answer.  In my installation, choosing a paper size in inches only changes the presets box.  The width, height and units are all still in 'mm', and the units are locked and grayed out.

Comment: This answer is incorrect- it only applies to the page size, not any other settings like guides.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change units of a page size to inches, select the page size you want, then switch the page size to Custom, which allows you to change the page units to inches. Then when you switch back to the page you first selected, it will display its size in inches. If you change the page size, it will remain in inches.

Although I haven’t tried it, you can probably skip the first step.

As far as I know, there is no way to set all layouts to default to inches. I’m using the latest version (3.24) and checked. This is especially annoying with the rulers, which will only display in mm.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [blog post](https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/7/2/setup-qgis-print-layout-to-use-inch-instead-of-millimeter-unit) to be helpful. Basically it involves saving a layout template (.qpt) file and editing it with a text editor, replacing "mm" with "in". If you save the edited template in the "composer_templates" directory under your profile e.g. /home/rich/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/composer_templates
it will be shown in the Layout Managers "New from Template" list.

Answer (score -4):

This is possible in QGIS >= 3.0.

Comment: What are the steps to make it happen?  I can't figure it out in 3.14

Comment: Please explain how to do it in QGIS 3.0 and above.

Comment: @ndawson Yours could be a very valuable answer if you detail the steps necessary to convert the units;)