# How to change ruler units in print composer to inches?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am using the latest version of QGIS, 2.16.1 and am having trouble changing the units displayed on the ruler in print composer from mm to inches. I can change the units of the page size no problem but that is about it.

Answer (score 3):

Someone may jump in to correct me here, but it appears that you can't as of QGIS 2.12 (rulers are hardcoded in mm). See User ndawson's post at the bottom of the gis.stackexchange post here: [How do I set the composer layout units to inches?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78926/how-do-i-set-the-composer-layout-units-to-inches)

Comment: Correct - it's not supported as of 2.16.