# How to display inches in the Print Composer margin guide

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I can't figure out how to change the margin guides in Print Composer to inches rather than metric.

In the "*Composition*" tab, under "*Page size*" I have *ANSI A (8.5 x 11 in)* selected.

However, the "*Units*" box below that is greyed out. The "*Guides and Grid*" section below that only gives options in terms of "*mm*".

This was indicated as fixed at

[How do I set the composer layout units to inches?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78926/how-do-i-set-the-composer-layout-units-to-inches)

However, as was noted there,

"I am having the same issue as above, and have not been able to reproduce your answer. In my installation, choosing a paper size in inches only changes the presets box. The width, height and units are all still in 'mm', and the units are locked and grayed out. – Get Spatial Oct 28 '15 at 23:13"

I am having the same experience as "Get Spatial". Does anyone have any idea why we continue to have this problem, although it seems to have been fixed for some?

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/168187/49538

Comment: okey,thanks for clarification is strange but you need select `Presets = Custom` ,after change comobobx `units` for `inch`value and select in Presets ANSI A ... or other

Comment: That worked to change it so it it says "inches" in the box in the Composition panel; however, it does not change the actual gude around the page--even if I "save" the project. That's still in mm. Then if you close the program and reopen, it reverts to mm in the box in the Composition Panel.

Comment: Sorry--I am running QGIS 2.18.14 with Windows 10.