# How To Set QGIS Map Units To Inches/Imperial?

Tags: qgis, mapping, units

I'm trying to recreate QGIS-equivalents of ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro maps originally created in inches/imperial units.  I wish to retain the same units for the QGIS maps but have run into problems.  I can't see how to universally change the units from mm to inch (many controls are greyed out).  I found this suggestion, which I tried, but it's problematic:

https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/7/2/setup-qgis-print-layout-to-use-inch-instead-of-millimeter-unit

I've produced a basic template with 11x8.5 inch dimensions and edited the "qgz" XML file, replacing all of the "mm" entries with "in" as suggested at the above link.  When I bring the template into a new project, the rulers are now indeed in inches.  However when I add an item like a label or scale bar, the fonts are incorrect.  An 8 point font is way too large.  Even if I set the font to 1 point, it is still too big.  It's evident that those controls still think the map is "mm" based (there are 25 mm/inch, so it is likely the 1 point fonts I'm seeing are actually equivalent to a 25 point font).

[image]

If I create another project and set the page size to letter size but leave the units in the default "mm", then the text for labels and scale bars are fine:

[image]

Is it possible to set up a project where all units are in inches and the rulers and controls behave correctly?  I found a similar question asked here, but it did not provide a workable solution:

[Setting composer layout units to inches in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78926/setting-composer-layout-units-to-inches-in-qgis)

Also note that this Github thread seems to indicate that as of a year ago, the problem had not been addressed:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29568